# Polynomial goal programming (PGP) optimization examples in python

Tags: python, optimization, polynomials, quadratic-programming, non-convex

To solve linear or quadratic programming problems in python, we often resort to `scipy.optimize.minimize`, which provides a heuristic platform to design optimization problems.

Could anyone refer me to examples of polynomial goal programming (PGP) in python? PGP is used to solve multi-objective non-convex optimization problems. To start, any scientific problem will do.

Comment: *To solve linear or quadratic programming problems in python, we often resort to scipy.optimize.minimize*  I have never encountered serious LP/QP applications using this, only student projects.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen do you know any example links that apply PGP in python?

Comment: No. Usually, we use piecewise linear formulations. This allows us to use off-the-shelf high-performance solvers. In practice, we don't need to use a precise polynomial function form to penalize the deviations as these typically have no direct physical meaning. So a piecewise linear formulation with just a few segments was always more than adequate in applications I was involved with.

Comment: the question is not whether PGP is adequate or student material, it's are there any python codes out there that conduct  PGP (so i can see how they run)